# Random Mac address changer with C#

Tags: c#, registry, mac-address

I'm a newbie developer!
I study C# now,
i want to change Mac address only use C# (with registry) (not bat OR cmd)
how can I do?
This code is Make Random 12 random string with english and number
and i want to change mac address to the random string..
Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace auto_mac_address_changer
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static string GetRandomPassword(int _totLen)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(); string input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, _totLen).Select(x => input[rand.Next(0, input.Length)]); return new string(chars.ToArray());
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


                bool networkUp = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();


            reg = reg.OpenSubKey("Software\\Your Program Name", true);


            while (true)
            {
                if (networkUp == false)
                {
                    string a = GetRandomPassword(12);
                    //here need to be change registry relative Mac Address

                }


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MAC Address? The hardware address associated with your NIC card?

Comment: yes. I Think I can change mac address with change registry..